How can I set bodylimit according to mutations in graphql & redwood & fastify?
I am trying to set the bodylimit according to the mutations in Redwoodjs. I want to set different bodyLimit due to different file sizes.
I tried to use @fastify/multipart with graphql in server.ts but i cant.
Currently, I have only set the bodyLimit globally for all mutations.
